# Python Jinja2 filtering

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

if my table is like this

[image: snippet]

how can I output the number of events with the same name, like test should be 5 and hello should be 3.

Edit:
Here's my Jinja2 code snippet

```
        {% for event in events %}
            {% set count = 0 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ event.name }}</td>
                {% for ticket in tickets %}
                    {% if ticket.event_name == event.name%}
                        {% set count = count + 1 %}
                    {% endif %}
       
                {% endfor %}
                <td>{{count}}<td>
                <td>
```

But its not counting right

Comment: This seems to be a database question and doesn't have much to do with the template engine (jinja2).

Comment: I am using jinja2 for frontend and trying to count the number of events

Comment: I have added my Jinja2 code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was able to solve it.

```
{% for event in events %}
            {% set count = namespace(value=0) %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ event.name }}</td>
                {% for ticket in tickets %}
                    {% if ticket.event_name == event.name%}
                        {% set count.value = count.value + 1 %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <td>{{count.value}}<td>
                <td>
```

Comment: You can also use  {{loop.index}} for counting numbers on a loop.

Comment: This wouldn't help in this exact situation but in case this helps you in the future, you can use {{ variable_name|length }} in order to get the length of the list using jinja2. Would not help in your current situation since you are needing to count based on condition statement